# Getting the second last value of a 4 digit integer

Tags: c++

I'm trying a lab exercise which wants user to input a 2 4-digit integer. Then the program will extract all the numbers in the 4-digit integer and use the number to do an arithmetic calculation just like the image link below.

[Arithmetic Calculation with 2 4-digit integer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Jww.jpg)

However, the objective for this lab exercise is not to allow me myself, to use a for loop to obtain the result.

For instance, when i want to obtain the last number of the 4 digit integer, I could easily do it by using this.

```
int firstDigit = firstNo % 10; //i will get 4 if the integer is 1234
int secondDigit = secondNo % 10; //i will get 8 if the integer is 5678
```

And of course table formatting is nothing to worry about before getting the logic right. Next is a very simple calculation of the numbers using the digit i obtain from the above.

```
int addfirstNumbers = firstDigit + secondDigit;
int minusfirstNumbers = firstDigit - secondDigit;
int multiplefirstNumbers = firstDigit * secondDigit;
int modfirstNumbers = firstDigit % secondDigit;
double divfirstNumbers = firstDigit / secondDigit;

cout << "add: " << addfirstNumbers << endl
     << "minus " << minusfirstNumbers << endl
     << "multipile " << multiplefirstNumbers << endl
     << "remainder " << modfirstNumbers << endl
     << "division " << divfirstNumbers << endl;
```

I do understand forloop can make my life easier. But i'm just trying out the long method before trying out the shorter way which is forloop.

But even before i proceed, I'm still unable to extract out the other digit from this 4 digit integer.

Comment: Hint: Divide your original number by 10. Whats this new numbers bottom digit?

Comment: what do you mean by "new numbers bottom digit"?

Comment: `while` loop can be used in place of `for` loop.

Comment: Sorry, the 'new number' I'm talking about is the number which is the old number divided by 10. `int newFirstNo = firstNo /10;`

Comment: @TeoChuenWeiBryan I believe they are referring to the least significant digit of the value resulting from an integer division operation.

Comment: @MikeVine do you mean divide the original number by 10 before the modulus?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Mike Vine mentioned in the comments, you can do integer division before taking the modulo.

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int x = 1234;
    std::cout << (x/10)%10 << "\n";
}
#Output
3
```

Edit: This works for all places of a number. To find the nth value from the end, just keep adding 0s to the divisor. For example to find the 2nd from the last, you'd want to divide x by 100 instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do

```
int secondLastDigit = ((i - (i % 10)) % 100)) / 10;
```

For i=5678:

`i % 10` (5678 % 10) equals 8

`i - (i % 10)` (5678 - 8) therefore equals 5670.

`(i - (i % 10)) % 100` (5670 % 100) equals 70

Finally `(i - (i % 10)) % 100) / 10` (70 / 10) = 7

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple, just use the modulus operator on the number for 100(`num%100`), getting the last two digits that way, and then divide that result by ten, and store the digit in an int (so the decimal is properly truncated.)